# display ShortDateString

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC app I am trying to display to display just the date part on the UI. The model.SomeDate is a DateTime value.

I tried the following:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor( model => model.SomeDate, new { @Value = Model.SomeDate.ToShortDateString() } )%>
```

But it won't compile, the error is:
**System.Nullable does not contain a definition for 'ToShortDateString' and no extension method...**

How can I make it work on the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
(Model.SomeDate.HasValue)?Model.SomeDate.Value.ToShortDateString():""
```

instead of

```
Model.SomeDate.ToShortDateString()
```

i.e:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor( model => 
     model.SomeDate, new { 
     @Value = Model.SomeDate.Value.ToShortDateString() 
   })
%>
```

Comment: Same thing. I can't invoke the ToShortDateString() mehod on the value being returned by the Model. It gives the same error.

Comment: Ok...Is `Mode.SomeDate` `DateTime?` datatype or some other datatype?

Comment: This won't work. You cannot override the `value` attribute of a textbox this way. The TextBoxFor helper will use the value of the model property passed in the lambda expression and completely ignore your value attribute.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Am afraid that's not true. You can assign a value using `@Value`

Comment: @dotNetNewbie, have you looked at your generated markup? I invite you to do so. You will notice the following: `<input Value="7/13/2012" id="Date" name="Date" type="text" value="7/13/2012 12:15:52 AM" />`. Notice how the `Value` attribute appears twice. Can you guess which one will be sent to the server when you submit this form? And, no, making it lowercase won't fix it.

Comment: @Chandu, I am afraid that is true. As I said **you cannot modify the value attribute** of the TextBox helpers using the htmlAttributes argument. Look at the broken markup that this produces. You have the Value attribute appearing twice on the input which results in undefined behavior. Might break any moment, with any browser, any time :-)

Comment: @Darin I have used in couple of the projects I worked on and I checked it now again it works fine....

Comment: By working fine you mean you get only one `value` attribute on your input field?

Answer (score 0):

You could use editor templates.

On your view model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? SomeDate { get; set; }
```

and on your view:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeDate) %>
```

And if for some reason the person that designed this application didn't use view models and decided to directly pass his domain models to the views and you cannot modify those domain models you could do this in your view:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeDate, "ShortDate") %>
```

and then define a custom editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ShortDate.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<DateTime?>" %>
<%= Html.TextBox(
    "", 
    Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("d") : "",
    new { @class = "text-box single-line" }
) %>
```

Comment: True. But I don't have control over the ViewModels code. I am just trying to figure out a solution that is easy to implement on the UI.

Comment: You don't have control over the ViewModels code? That's probably one of the most contradictory sentence I have ever heard. A view model is something that you specifically design for the requirements of your view. It is where you define the way the data should be formatted and displayed on the view. I think you are mistaking the notion of ViewModel. What you have is not a view model. It's a domain model. It's something entirely different. It's something that has no place in a view. Something you should never pass to a view. Anyway, for your case I have included a possible solution.

Comment: Sorry, I was a little confused and may be didn't explain the scenario in detail. I meant that we cannot make changes to the existing viewmodels code due to a company specific reason. So, I was wondering if there is a way to handle this on the View/UI w/o touching the ViewModels code.

Comment: Yes, there is, as I have shown. But I can't imagine a reason why you cannot modify the view models other than what you have is not view models. A simply cannot call a class that you don't have control on a view model. If this is the case you could always write a real view model for your application and then map between the thing that your company doesn't allow you to modify and the view model.